# Jquery not working when page is refreshed in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, label, placeholder

I am dealing with the following jQuery issue in IE.

For a form I need to replace the default placeholders fields, this is done by jquery, placeholder is hidden and the value of it is added to a position:absolute label on the input.

This all works as I want but, the problem I am facing; When I am filling down te form, the values are set (in a session). After submit I go to the second step. I can go back to the first stap by clicking a link.

This is the situation when I just fill down the form element OR I do a hard browser refresh
like F5.

[image]

When I just hit the link in the tempalte to go back one stap, this is the result
[image]

The custom placeholder (as a label in red) should be hidden but won't do this as I aspect I should have to. I am facing this issue only in IE (?)

Below some js code I am using;

```
$(function(e) {
    //id itterator if the inputs don't have ids

    if ($('input#firstname').val()) {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('.firstname-label').hide();
    }

        var phid=0;
        $.fn.placeholder = function(){
            return this.bind({
                focus: function(){
                    $(this).parent().addClass('placeholder-focus');
                },blur: function(){
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('placeholder-focus');
                },'keyup input': function(){
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('placeholder-changed', this.value!=='');
                }
            }).each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                //Adds an id to elements if absent
                if(!this.id) this.id='ph_'+(phid++); 
                //Create input wrapper with label for placeholder. Also sets the for attribute to the id of the input if it exists.
                $('<span class="placeholderWrap"><label class="'+this.id+'-label" for="'+this.id+'">'+$this.attr('placeholder')+'</label></span>')
                    .insertAfter($this)
                    .append($this); 
                //Disables default placeholder
                //$this.attr('placeholder','').keyup();
            });
        };

        console.log('set placeholders');

        $('input').each(function() {  

           var input = $(this);
           var id     = $(this).attr('id');

           if (!$(this).val() && $(this).attr('id') != 'photo') {
           $('input#' + id).placeholder('');
           console.log(id);
           } else {
           // do nothing
           }
        });
});
```

Thanks in advance!